# htaccess RewriteRule and Redirect 301 interfering with one another

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My .htaccess file includes this, which allows the URL structure in my ExpressionEngine site to function:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

However, it is interfering with what I'm trying to do here, redirecting an old page:

```
Redirect 301 /old-url/ /
```

This is what I see in my browser address after I load the /old-url/ address:

```
https://www.domain.test/?/old-url/
```

If I take out the RewriteRule, my Redirect 301 works, but all the navigation in the site breaks. Is there some way for me to make an exception where I want to redirect old URLs? I have inherited someone else's work in this case.

Edit: here is my entire .htaccess file content:

```
RewriteEngine On

Redirect 301 /in-loving-memory-of-our-partners /
Redirect 301 /in-loving-memory-of-our-partners/ /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml$ /sitemap/xml [NC,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(assets|emergency|portalimages|images|system|themes|test|AUL|swfs|favicon\.ico|robots\.txt|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.well-known) - [L]
```

Comment: You want to learn about the differences between the flags `L` and `END`. The `L` flag stops the rewriting process _for this iteration_ , not completely. So both rules get applied one after another. Which is not what you want.

Comment: I've tried a variety of combinations of [L] and [END] but nothing is working. Either it doesn't update the URL as I wanted, or it breaks the entire website and I get an internal server error.

Comment: I added the entire contents of .htaccess to my original post. The two Redirect 301 lines are where I am working. If I add [L] or [END] to those lines, the website breaks and I get an internal server error.

Comment: I would do those redirects via RewriteRule as well here, rather than trying to figure out how these different types of directives from different modules interfere with each other. `RewriteRule ^in-loving-memory-of-our-partners/?$ / [R=301,L]` should probably do the trick. (And I would probably not go to extreme lengths to try and make the HTTPS redirect happen at the same time. If you ended up with two consecutive redirects for this one specific URL only, that would likely not be the end of the world.)

Comment: That seems to work great, thank you!